# planar graph ans complement Grapf

Tags: combinatorics

G=(v,e) is a simple planar graph with |v|>10 vertices.
I need to prove that G#=(V,E#)-the complement of G- is not a plannar graph.

I tried to use Euler's formuala, but it didnt went well.

Comment: yes, wonderful!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that the total number of vertices of $G$ is $n$ and $n \geq 11$. By the Euler formula, we know that if $G$ is a planar graph, then $|E(G)| \leq 3n-6 $. On the other hand, $E(G)+E(\bar G) =\binom{n}{2}.$ So 
$E(\bar G) = \binom{n}{2} -E(G) \geq \frac{n(n-1)}{2}-3n+6 > 3n -6$ (since $n \geq 11$) and so $\bar G$ is not a planar graph.